# PhoneGap Build: SocialSharing Plugin Not Loading

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, socialshare

I am trying to use the SocialSharing Plugin with PhoneGap Build.

I have put the following into the config.ml file:

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.0.8" />
```

Here is a sample of my HTML index page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SocialSharing.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="landmarks" data-role="page">
            <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('My message')">share!</button>
            <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only')">message only</button>
            <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message via Twitter')">message via Twitter</button>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I tap the buttons (after downloading the app from PhoneGapBuild) nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to switch to the PhoneGap/Cordova Command Line Interface to build this app. When I did, the SocialSharing plugin began to work perfectly.

I believe the problem was that I had not correctly imported the `cordova.js` and `SocialSharing.js` files into the index.html page when I uploaded my source to PhoneGap Build.

Note to Everyone: it is important to have the `cordova.js` script be the first script you import in your HTML page, as you may inadvertently use a function that relies on the Cordova platform, and, if the `cordova.js` file is imported later, the feature will not work.

Answer (score 1):

For thouse using cordova 3.6.3 or so
I had the same problem and found that calling plugins by window.plugins is now deprecated and already not working for me.

I submited an issue to the plugin owner and changed for my self the plugin.
just need to change the footer of the plugin js with

```
--deleted window.plugins.socialsharing....
module.exports= new SocialSharing();
```

Not calling any window.plugin etc...
and from your js 
    socialsharing=cordova.require("nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing.SocialSharing");
then you can use 
    socialsharing.share(...)
Hope this helps someone!