# Phonegap plugin not loading

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use a Phonegap plugin called Socialsharing on the PhoneGap android emulator app but it won't load.

steps tried:

- cli: phonegap plugin add nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
- cli: phonegap prepare
- cli: phonegap build
- instructions on [PhoneGap Build: SocialSharing Plugin Not Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24073950/phonegap-build-socialsharing-plugin-not-loading)
- cordova.require("nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing.SocialSharing");  -> Not found error message
- window.plugins.socialsharing isn't there, but i've heard that it is deprecated

In the console i'm seeing this:

```
[phonegap] 200 /plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.insomnia/www/Insomnia.js
```

but nothing about the socialsharing plugin

How can i debug/solve this?

Comment: Try it on a proper phone. the plugins don't work in-browser but I never use the emulator so I don't know about them working in it or not.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  If so, please share.  I know it is old but I am having the exact same problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are pointing to is for the `PhoneGap Build` online service. For local builds you need to do this:

```
phonegap plugin add nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing
```

then:

```
phonegap build
```

Comment: I've already done that, tried it again to be sure.. no change.